# C++ Operator Overloading

Tags: c++

Is operator overloading for classes and structs always resolved at compile-time?

Answer (score 7):

**Yes, always.**

Comment: I wondered because apparently it isn't in Delphi, because there are speed differences

Comment: @Lort: This sort of information should be part of your question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Only dynamic type-specific behavior achievable in C++ is through virtual member functions.

Comment: And note that operator overloads can be virtual member functions. The overload is still resolved at compile-time, though, so the answer is correct. It's the override which is dynamic.

Comment: @Steve - nice distinction & explanation.